# .htaccess Domain Name 301 redirect with exclusion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I managed to create a basic rule set with htaccess to redirect with 301 all requests that a user types for the *.domain.com

So all : *.domain.com requests redirect to www.home.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.home\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.home.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now i'm trying to modify it and redirect with 302 all requests that didn't have originally the *.home.domain.com but continue to keep previous conditions

I have read some of the replies already but i'm puzzled from the regex syntax to apply a reply that is given similar for my case.

Update : Thanks Jon Lin for your reply, one more clarification

It's my fault from the start, i understood it when i read your reply

I want all :

```
*.home.domain.com >> 301 >> www.home.domain.com
not *.home.domain.com >> 302 >> www.google.com (for example)
```

Update 2 :

Will this work ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.home\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^www\.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.home.domain.com [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.home\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# all : *.domain.com requests redirect to www.home.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.home.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# all requests that didn't have originally the *.home.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.home.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```